# Resources & tips for beginning with Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, resources

I recently found out that I will be part of a project that will use Silverlight. Since I will be doing interface design for this application I was wondering if I could get help with some tips & resources.

1. **So what are the tips that you wish you had gotten when you started with Silverlight?**
2. **And what resources have you found valuable for starting and progressing with Silverlight?**

---

Already found a similar post but I still would like more:

- [Good resource for learning Silverlight 2 development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203466/good-resource-for-learning-silverlight-2-development)

---

**Clarification:**
I will be creating the interface for an application where the back-end stuff (algorithms) are being created by a developer intern (I'm an intern also).

Comment: It would help to know what kind of development you are doing. Are you more interested in whiz-bang controls or data-heavy LOB apps? For the former, you'll want to concentrate on the numerous visual features that XAML/WPF provide. For the latter, you'll want to get a solid understanding of good architecture practices and data binding concepts.

Comment: Well the things is that I'm having a hard time even knowing what it was you just said. I know what WPF is and LOB is i guess Line Of Business. But I have no clue what whiz-bang is. So it is very basic stuff for beginning to understand even those concepts. *Editing my initial question"

Answer (score 2):

[QuickStarts](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/) silverlight.net Quickstarts for several different topics.